# Programming a macro to run other macros on each worksheet

Tags: excel, automation, vba

I have an excel workbook with many different sheets. Each sheet has a single macro in it wich saves the sheet as a pdf and opens outlook with that pdf as an attachment. I am looking for a function to place on one worksheet that will run each macro without having to manually run each on their respective worksheets.

Comment: For/Each loop. Show us your function, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say there is a macro in each worksheet called **SheetMac.**  Put the following in a standard module and run it:

```
Sub MASTER()
For Each sh In Sheets
    sh.Activate
    Call sh.SheetMac
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: tried this, getting error: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

FYI macro name is: RDB_Worksheet_Or_Worksheets_To_PDF_And_Create_Mail

Comment: got it to work with this:

`Sub RunAll()

Dim SHt As Worksheet
For Each SHt In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
SHt.Activate

Call RDB_Worksheet_Or_Worksheets_To_PDF_And_Create_Mail

Next SHt
End Sub`